# Mercurial: How to re-include ignored files after the merge

Tags: mercurial

In mercurial, the merge ignored some files (possibly a human mistake). How I can 're-include' the ignored files?

Scenario: the merge target(rev #47) has 5 files, but the merge(rev #50) has included just 1 file and others are ignored.

[image: merge target]

[image: after the merge]

Apparently, when I check the resulting code, the code from Rev# 47 is missing.

Comment: actually i am confused what's going on here

Comment: Highlight 46 and 50, right click "visual diff". I think you will find changes in more than one file.

Answer (score 0):

You probably did the merge in a way you didn't intend, e.g. telling hg to only accept changes from one branch, discarding the changes from the merged rev47.

The easiest way is to start with a repo where the merge did not happen and re-do the merge. This is not possible, if it is a shared repo and that merge is already shared with others. If it everything local, but if that repo is your only copy, make a new clone without the merge: `hg clone -r49 OLDREPO .`

Thus if you cannot simply re-do the merge on a new repo without that merge, you'll have to go a longer way which is summarized [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152480/how-can-i-back-out-a-merge-in-mercurial-and-later-remerge-with-that-branch). Note the screenshot in the accepted answer and DO NOT discard the changes from the merge target.