# Revert pushed bad merge in hg

Tags: mercurial, kallithea

I stated working by creating a new branch (say) new-feature and done all the changes ( a lot of files has been changed).

And I wrongly merged it with a branch say 'my-client' branch where every one works and **pushed the code to the repository**. **I want to remove the merge I've done.**
No other developers currently working on branch 'my-client'.

```
I have tried 

    hg backout <REV>    // rev of the bad merge
    abort: cannot backout a merge changeset.
```

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I back out a merge in Mercurial and later remerge with that branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152480/how-can-i-back-out-a-merge-in-mercurial-and-later-remerge-with-that-branch)

Comment: @stayon Target Thank you for your help.  I resolved it in the following way 1. hg backout <REV-before bad commit> 2. made a change in a file(put a blank line) 3. commit 4. push